# Set theoretic image of Spec of a filtered colimit of $A$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We assume all rings are commutative.
Let $A$ be a ring.
Let $I$ be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $F\colon I \rightarrow A$-alg be a functor, where $A$-alg is the category of $A$-algebras.
We write
$X = Spec(A)$,
$B_i = F(i)$ for each $i \in I$,
$B =$ colim $B_i$,
$Y_i = Spec(B_i)$ for each $i\in I$,
$Y = Spec(B)$.
Let $f\colon Y \rightarrow X$, $f_i\colon Y_i \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphisms.

Then $f(Y) = \bigcap f_i(Y_i)$?

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that $\bigcap f_i(Y_i) \subset f(Y)$.
Let $x \in \bigcap f_i(Y_i)$.
Suppose $x \in X - f(Y)$.
Then $f^{-1}(x) = \emptyset$.
Since $f^{-1}(x) =$ Spec $(B \otimes_A \kappa(x)), B \otimes_A \kappa(x) = 0$.
Since $B \otimes_A \kappa(x) =$ colim $(B_i \otimes_A \kappa(x))$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $B_i \otimes_A \kappa(x) = 0$. Hence $f_i^{-1}(x) = \emptyset$.
This is a contradiction.
**QED**